# All possible combinations of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem finding all combinations of a 2D array.
Let's suggest I have an array as follwoing:

```
[  
[1,2],  
[3,4],  
[5,6]  
]
```

Now I need to get all possible combninations such as

```
[  
[1,3,5],  
[1,3,6],  
[1,4,5],  
[1,4,6],  
[2,3,5],  
[2,3,6],  
[2,4,5],  
[2,4,6]  
]
```

I've managed to get it with numpy and meshgrids with single arrays:

```
import numpy as np
array_1 = np.array([1,2])
array_2 = np.array([3,4])
array_3 = np.array([5,6])

combination = np.array(np.meshgrid(array_1, array_2, array_3)).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

But with a 2D array I cant't get it to work.

```
import numpy as np
multi = [np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4]), np.array([5,6])]
combination = np.array(np.meshgrid(multi)).T.reshape(-1,len(multi))
```

This doesn't give me the expected result but only:

```
[  
[1,2,3],  
[4,5,6]  
]
```

Is there any way to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `itertools` package in the standard library.
`itertools.product` generates all combinations that you wish.

```py
import itertools
arrays = [
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6]  
]  
list(itertools.product(*arrays))
#[(1, 3, 5),
# (1, 3, 6),
# (1, 4, 5),
# (1, 4, 6),
# (2, 3, 5),
# (2, 3, 6),
# (2, 4, 5),
# (2, 4, 6)]
```

If you prefer lists to tuples, you can do the following:

```py
list(map(list, itertools.product(*arrays)))
#[[1, 3, 5],
# [1, 3, 6],
# [1, 4, 5],
# [1, 4, 6],
# [2, 3, 5],
# [2, 3, 6],
# [2, 4, 5],
# [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exact what I was looking for